# Oracle 12c PLSQL MERGE error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, toad, oracleforms

The below code snippet is from a larger procedure of mine. When I execute this procedure manually in TOAD it works without error as I would expect.

I am now trying to put it into a form for the user - however when I try to compile it I get the following error on the MERGE line:
"Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
:=.(@%;"

```
MERGE INTO count_balance cb
USING (select location_code, product_code, closing_stock
       from trd_stock_closing ts
      where period = gen.add_periods(p_period, -1)
        and exists (select null
                      from ag_product_view
                     where product_code = ts.product_code
                       and group_code = 'Q')) cs
ON (cb.location_code = cs.location_code AND cb.product_code = cs.product_code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET cb.opening_stock = cs.closing_stock
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (location_code, product_code, opening_stock)
VALUES (cs.location_code, cs.product_code, cs.closing_stock);
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: You might try fully qualifying all table names with their schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use good old Oracle*Forms, which have no support for MERGE statement at all. Try either use the newer version of Forms or wrap this code into stored procedure.